# how to add function in buttons appended by DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add function to the button  "CLICK ME TO EDIT" But any ideas how?

```
var comment = prompt("Type content for new paragraph here", "");
var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
newParagraph.textContent = comment;
document.getElementById("hijibiji").appendChild(newParagraph);
var b = document.createElement("button");
var t=document.createTextNode("CLICK ME TO EDIT");
b.appendChild(t);
document.getElementById("hijibiji").appendChild(b);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="hijibiji"> </div>
```

Comment: `addEventListener` comes to mind ?

Comment: this should work, if the element `hijibiji` is already defined in your html.

Comment: Uhm, are you inserting a `prompt()` as textContent for a paragraph ?

Comment: @adeneo yep.. prompt takes the content that i want to insert.....

Comment: basically i wan to edit the paragraph created by var newparagraph

Comment: Oh, I see! Did you just try `b.onclick = function() { alert(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var comment = prompt("Type content for new paragraph here", "");
var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
newParagraph.textContent = comment;
document.getElementById("hijibiji").appendChild(newParagraph);
var b = document.createElement("button");
var t=document.createTextNode("CLICK ME TO EDIT");
b.appendChild(t);
document.getElementById("hijibiji").appendChild(b);

b.onclick = (function() {
    var edit = prompt("Type to edit", "");
    newParagraph.innerHTML = edit;
});
```

**DEMO :** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ks94C/)